# Where does TeXShop stores the console output?

Tags: pdftex, texshop

I'm using pdflatexmk with TeXShop and I would like to search in the console output. TeXShop itself does not allow this (I even can't select the output), but I can not find a log file containing a copy of the console output. There's only a log file that gets overwritten by the pdflatexmk script.

Can I generate a file containing the console output?

Comment: The information in the log file is richer than that in the console output.

Comment: For my purpose it's not unfortunately. The pdflatexmk script does several runs and each run is marked in the console output with the line `Run number`. This run number for example is not carried over to the log file.

Comment: The log file is rewritten at each run. I believe it's possible to ask `latexmk` to rename the log file adding a time stamp before rerunning LaTeX.